# How to create a common component for numbers-only input validation in ReactJS using Material-UI TextField?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using MUI TextField. My task is to make validation only for numbers these **eE+-** keys will not be accepted. I want to make a standard component for this using onChange. I want to handle this if this key **eE+-** will enter by the user. I need to throw an error for not valid I tried some want but not working correctly because for a number this field will be considered undefined also I don't want the user to restrict from the keyword because in some cases also are valid.

```
this is valid 
+1
-1
1e1

this blow is invalid
e
1-
1+
12e
```

```
const NumberField = ({ ...props }) => {
  return (
    <TextField
      {...props}
      type="number"
      //   inputProps={{ inputMode: 'numeric', pattern: '/^(0|[1-9]d*)$/' }}
      onChange={(e) => {
        if (e.target.value === '' || !/[eE+-]/.test(e.target.value)) {
          props.onChange(e);
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }}
      error={props.errorMsg}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Looks like the `onChange` is not firing on letters when `type="number"`

Answer (score 0):

make your reusable numeric textField like this:

```
import { TextField as MuiTextField, TextFieldProps } from "@mui/material";
import * as styles from "./styles";
import type * as types from "./types";

const TextField: React.FC<TextFieldProps> = (props: types.ITextFieldProps) => {
  const { sx, required, label, ...restProps } = props;
  const sxStyle = { ...styles.input, ...sx };

  return (
    <MuiTextField
      fullWidth
      size="small"
      sx={sxStyle}
      label={
        label ? (
          <>
            {label} {required ? "*" : ""}
          </>
        ) : undefined
      }
      onKeyPress={enNumberConvertor}
      {...restProps}
    />
  );
};

export { TextField };
export default TextField;
```

and pass enNumberConvertor function to onKeyPress

```
const Number = /^[0-9]+$/;

const enNumberConvertor = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
let regex = new RegExp(Number);
  let str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
  if (regex.test(str)) return true;
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
};
```

also this is regex for decimal and decimal positive numbers

```
const decimalNumber = /^(-)?\d*(\.\d{0,3})?$/g;
const decimalPositiveNum = /^\d*(\.\d{0,3})?$/g;
```

Comment: no, I don't want to restrict users from keywords I just want to throw an error if only this eE+- value gets entered for example only e is invalid, +1 is valid but 1+ is invalid and 1e1 is vaild